# React - how to pass multiple input values to child in on change event when values have different types (is not always e.target.value)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple input fields and 1 react-select dropdown field. I created a method in my parent component that sets the state with the values from the input, passes it down to the child which should call the method. My problem is that react-select doesn't take the value but an object like this:

```
{value: 'xy', name:'x', label: 'y'}
```

so normally my function in my onChange event handler would look like this (when passing multiple values):

in parent:

```
testing(e) {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
}
```

in child:

```
<input type="text" name="maxfare" onChange={this.onChange}/>
...
onChange(e){
   var value = [e.target.name] = e.target.value;
   this.props.onChange(value);
}
...
```

However, while my input fields take:

```
e.target.value
```

my select dropdown takes entire 'e' - not e.target.value. I tried to pass my onChange function in child component 2 arguments, calling my method in parent with 2, but that doesn't to work. Any help would be great! My code is below (the relevant parts- if I forgot something that you think is important, please let me know). Ps. I thought about having 2 onChange functions, passing once my value for select dropdown and a second one doing the rest, but then I would need to pass 2 onChange methods to the child and I believe thats not possible in react?! Thanks!!:

Parent:

```
...
 onChangeT(selectValue, value) {
    this.setState({
        origin: selectValue,
        maxfare: value
        ...       
    })
}
render(){
....
  <Parent cities={this.state.citiesToSelect} origin={this.state.origin} maxfare={this.state.maxfare} onChange={this.onChangeT}/>
...
}
```

Child:

```
....
onChangeC(e){
    var value = [e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.props.onChange(e, value);
    console.log("name",  name)
}
....
<Select
     onChange={this.onChangeC}
     labelKey='name'
     value={this.props.origin}
     options={this.props.cities}                 
/>
<input type="text" name="maxfare" onChange={this.onChangeC}/>
```

Comment: What is `var value = [e.target.name] = e.target.value;` meant to be doing? Seems like some very odd logic

Comment: Also all these `...`s are making the code really difficult to read, for me personally at least

Comment: i kinda just wanted to store [e.target.name] = e.target.value; in 'value'. I put the ... in hope the code is more readable as i only included parts of the code- I guess that didn't work for you :-D

Comment: `[e.target.name] = e.target.value` will destructure `e.target.value`, aka choose the first element in the array that it assumes `e.target.value` contains. Then will assign that to `value`. Is this your intention? Not wanting to come off as patronising, just not sure if it's what you were intending. Doing chained assignments is baaaad too, because the value between the `=` signs will actually be global, rather than var scoped.

Comment: Regarding the `...`, tbh I'd rather just see the full code with the imports and class names and stuff, otherwise it's hard to see how everything glues together, whether those components are in render functions, etc. Also it means people can run the code themselves if they wish. Although respect for wanting to make it more MCVE-ish

Comment: no that was not my intention. my only intention is to 'update' the parent component with the 2 different values. If my code isn't clear enough, I could also edit and paste my entire code?

Answer (score 1):

#### We want to be able to do this in the parent

```
  onChange = (name, value) => {
    this.setState({[name]: value});
  }
```

We fix the "wiring" of the children `onChange` to do exactly that, raise an `onChange` with a `name` and a `value`. Wrap `react-select` and provide a consistent interface to the parent.

#### Form example

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Input from './Input';
import Select from './Select';

export default class Form extends React.Component {
  state = {
    input: '',
    select: '',
    options: ['A', 'B', 'C']
  };

  onChange = (name: string, value: string) => {
    this.setState({[name]: value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <Input
          label="Surname"
          name={'input'}
          value={this.state.input}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <Select
          label="Grade"
          name={'select'}
          value={this.state.select}
          options={this.state.options}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

#### Input example

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default class Input extends React.Component {
  onChange = (e) => {
    const {onChange, name} = this.props;
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(name, e.currentTarget.value);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>{this.props.label}</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name={this.props.name}
          value={this.props.value}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

#### And a DOM native `<Select />` example

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default class Select extends React.Component {
  onChange = (e) => {
    const {onChange, name} = this.props;
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(name, e.currentTarget.value);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>{this.props.label}</label>
        <select
          name={this.props.name}
          value={this.props.value}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        >
          {this.props.options.map(o => <option key={o}>{o}</option>)}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that property initialisers/class fields (or whatever they're called) require a babel plugin to work.

Comment: Thank you, but I have a lot of input fields (just showed 2 here for simplicity) and it would be bad if I created like you suggest, for every input field an own component.

Comment: If all of them are input fields then you create many `<Input />` instances not new Components.

Comment: so you don't think there is a way to just have 1 function insight one component like I was trying to do?

Comment: See this answer also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740235/react-js-create-input-elements-from-json-schema/47740808#47740808

Comment: You will have one `onChange` handling all change events in the parent as I say in the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Okay thanks! I tried to implement your solutions, however since when I use yours, I have to pass data grandparent-child-grandchild, its not really working. Can I perhaps edit my question with the code so you can see what I mean? ps. I can't take you solution and have to have 3 components then, because I cannot have the form insight my parent component-it must be in the child (I have more code than just a form) if I use select and input as separate components

Comment: Create a `<Form />` component to encapsulate the state of all input components. If you need access to that state outside of the <Form /> then you need to pull it further up the component hierarchy and pass it as a prop to the <Form />. Assuming you are not using Redux.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#usage) doesn't return a native event nor a similar object shape of a native event, is forcing you to normalize the shape of the object that returned from it. You can do that by wrapping the `Select` component of react-select with your own component and returning a custom object for your use-case.

In this example we are trying to normalize the behavior of our `onChange` event both for inputs and `Select`. We will first check if the object that returned is having a `target` key, if it does we know that this is a native event that we are handling and we will set the state according to the name of the input and its value (exactly how you did it in your example).

If we don't have a `target` key, then we may handle a different kind of event.
We will check if we get a `selectedValue` key (just a convention between yourself, you can change the key as you like), then we will set the state by its `name` and `selectedValue` that we received.

This will only work if you will pass the name upwards of course.
So the object that you need to return from the custom `Select` component should look something like this:

```
    {name: this.props.name, selectedValue } 
// where selectedValue is the object received from the real Select component
```

Here is a running example:

```js
const options = [
  { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
  { value: 'two', label: 'Two' },
]

const moreOptions = [
  { value: 'mike', label: 'johnson' },
  { value: 'lynda', label: 'bog' },
]

class MySelect extends React.Component {

  handleChange = selectedValue => {
    const { name, onChange } = this.props;
    onChange({ name, selectedValue });
  }

  render() {
    const { options, value, ...rest } = this.props;
    return (
      <Select
        {...rest}
        value={value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={options}
      />
    );
  }
}


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      option1: '',
      option2: '',
      value1: 1,
      value2: '',
      value3: 3,
    }
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    let nextState;
    if (e.target) {
      const { name, value } = e.target;
      nextState = { [name]: value };
    } else if (e.selectedValue) {
      const { name, selectedValue } = e;
      nextState = { [name]: selectedValue };
    }

    this.setState(nextState);
  }

  render() {
    const { value1, value2, value3, option1, option2 } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <MySelect
          value={option1.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          options={options}
          name="option1"
        />
        <div>
          <span>input1 </span>
          <input value={value1} name="value1" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>input2 </span>
          <input value={value2} name="value2" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>input3 </span>
          <input value={value3} name="value3" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>

        <MySelect
          value={option2.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          options={moreOptions}
          name="option2"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.5.10/prop-types.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/classnames@2.2.5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-input-autosize@2.0.0/dist/react-input-autosize.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-select/dist/react-select.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/react-select/dist/react-select.css">
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: So App is the parent and Select is the child in your code but then you render the inputs (apart from select) inside the parent (App). I haven't used react for too long but I wanted to have all of the inputs (select dropdown and other inputs) rendered in the child, in the parent I would only render the child to make a clear separation

Comment: `App` is just an arbitrary name for a component, it could be a child of another component

Comment: I know, what I mean is that it 'works' here as the parent and if so, the inputs are inside the parent

Comment: where is the problem with this approach then?

Comment: Im trying to structure it logically, therefore putting form elements into the same component or at least into grandchildren. If i put my form elements (inputs and select) in different components such as one in the parent and the rest in the child, then there is no point of dealing with passing values etc- then I could just have one component for everything (inputs and select)

Comment: the main issue here is that `react-select` is already a custom component that wraps a native `DOM` element (`<select>`). so if you want a one handler for all input types you will need more logic inside the handle function and on top of that you will need to wrap `react-select` as well in order to normalize the data shape it sends back via its own handlers. you can see how it is done in the example i provided, you can easily transform the `App` component i created to a `Form` component. i'm sorry but i still don't understand the issue you are facing now :)

Comment: my problem is not that you named the component App :) Im saying that if I have like you suggested the inputs in the parent and the select in the child, then there is not need for all the 'trouble' because i can just put all into one component and won't have any issues (here I could just have 2 methods where one is taking care of setting the value for inputs and another for setting the select. When I have parent/child components, I think it only makes sense to structure it logically thus putting all inputs and select into the child or other grandchild components.